# How to get return value of smart contract by calling encoded function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js

I have encoded function of my smart contract, which has methodID and parameters i.e. `0xf7ea7a3d4000000000000000000015000000000000000000ff7f0000b200000000f7ea7a..............`. Suppose, in this encoded function, there are also two arguments, one is uint and the other is a string.  This encoded function actually is a getter (not changing status) of my contract (means in ABI its stateMutability =view) and also it return a value i.e. `totalSupply`. Now, I want to call this function through web3js/nodejs, as below. This code gives me transaction receipt/hash, as expected, but I am interested to retrieve the getter function return value i.e. `totalSupply`;

```js
try {
    await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
        {
            from: account1,
            to: myContAddr,
            data: myFunc
        }).then(function (res) {
            console.log("Normal Getter", res);
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(" Normal Getters: ERROR !");
}
```

One **possible solution** is to extract function Signature/methodID (which is easy for me) from given encoded function and its parameters (yet, not known to me how to decode parameters) and call the function like this .. i.e.

```js
try {
    res = await myContractInstance.methods[myFuncID](????).call({ from: account1 })  // without parameters
    console.log("Getter output", res);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Getter output: ERROR !", error);
}
```

So, my questions are

1. How to decode parameters from above mentioned encoded function, to proceed as per my mentioned solution (if my solution is correct)?
2. Or is there any other feasible/easy procedure to call such an encoded (getter) function?